# Is div turned 180deg on Y-axis (3D) rendered?

Tags: performance, css

I was wondering, I have table of 5*(8 to 11) cells that are all 3D flipcard. I am not really sure if it can hit performance (I am not seeing any problems, but...), or if it would hit on mobile.
I fought about hiding the content on the back side of flipcards. Should I use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` does it do any difference in rendering speed?

Comment: I wouldn't think it would hinder performance if you use `backface-visibility:hidden`, but I have no evidence to back that up